What makes an NFT be considered a wrapped NFT?
When you bridge an NFT let's say through Wormhole NFT bridge then on the destination chain it creates a wrapped NFT. This is done by deploying a separate ERC-721 contract for every unique combination of chain ID & NFT contract address using create2 assembly function and minting the NFT of same token ID and URI. What I want to know is why is this considered "wrapped" let's say instead of Wormhole deploying the contract themselves, they mint on a predefined contract address by the same NFT brand then will it still be considered wrapped or not?

If Wormhole mint on a predefined contract address, the NFT would still be wrapped because a wrapped NFT is an NFT which is locked on the original chain.

But what about during migration of NFTs from one chain to another where the original NFTs will be burned before bridging?

In case of migration, the NFT wouldn't be considered wrapped because there's nothing to wrap on the original chain.
